# Mercurial: no ~/.hgrc file

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to go though [this tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678) that says:

---

**Enable SSH compression for Mercurial**

Edit the Mercurial global configuration file (~/.hgrc).
Add the following line to the UI section:

`ssh = ssh -C`

---

But there is no that file in my system. HG of course is installed.

Comment: From the Mercurial documentation: [*These files do not exist by default and you will have to create the appropriate configuration files yourself*](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not there by default. You don't need it to exist — it just *can* exist to customize how you use Mercurial. You just need to create a `.hgrc` file in your home directory and it should work.

Heres a great intro post:
[http://hgtip.com/tips/beginner/2009-09-30-configuring-mercurial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120824162725/http://hgtip.com/tips/beginner/2009-09-30-configuring-mercurial/)

Answer (score 10):

Snagged from the manpages at https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html.

> **Files**
>
> Mercurial reads configuration data from several files, if they exist.
>   *These files do not exist by default and you will have to create the
>   appropriate configuration files yourself:*
>
> Local configuration is put into the per-repository /.hg/hgrc
>   file.
>
> Global configuration like the username setting is typically put into:
>
> ```
> %USERPROFILE%\mercurial.ini
> $HOME/.hgrc
> ```
>
> The names of these files depend on the system on which Mercurial is
>   installed. *.rc files from a single directory are read in alphabetical
>   order, later ones overriding earlier ones. Where multiple paths are
>   given below, settings from earlier paths override later ones.
>
> On Unix, the following files are consulted:
>
> - /.hg/hgrc (per-repository)
> - $HOME/.hgrc (per-user)
> - /etc/mercurial/hgrc (per-installation)
> - /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc (per-installation)
> - /etc/mercurial/hgrc (per-system)
> - /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/*.rc (per-system)
> - /default.d/*.rc (defaults)
>
> On Windows, the following files are consulted:
>
> - /.hg/hgrc (per-repository)
> - %USERPROFILE%.hgrc (per-user)
> - %USERPROFILE%\Mercurial.ini (per-user)
> - %HOME%.hgrc (per-user)
> - %HOME%\Mercurial.ini (per-user)
> - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mercurial (per-installation)
> - \hgrc.d*.rc (per-installation)
> - \Mercurial.ini (per-installation)
> - /default.d/*.rc (defaults)

Answer (score 1):

For up-to-date versions of mercurial, you should use the [XDG](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) compatible location. Unless you explicitly set `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` the settings should go into the file:

```
~/.config/hg/hgrc
```

Less clutter in your home directory and `~/.config/hg/` can also be used for files like a common `hgignore`